# nest array return from php web service using nusoap lib

Tags: php, web-services, nusoap

I want to return nested array from web service in php upto i have do like this way

```
$ordArr = array("orderid"=>$orderId,"orderdate"=>$orderdate,"ordertype"=>$ordertype);

$userArr = array("userid"=>$userId,"name"=>$name,"address"=>$address);
```

i am able to define complex type for single array and return single array using this way

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
 'User',
 'complexType',
 'struct',
 'all',
 '',
      array(
       'userId' => array('name' => 'userId',
           'type' => 'xsd:int'),
       'name' => array('name' => 'name',
           'type' => 'xsd:string'),
       'address' => array('name' => 'address',
           'type' => 'xsd:string')
      )
);
```

but how to define complext type for the nested array like

```
$userArr = array("userid"=>$userId,"name"=>$name,"address"=>$address,"order"=>$ordArr);
```

i little bit confused into the type define in complex type for array

like for string set type as 'xsd:string' but for the array type=?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the nested array used into the addcomplextype using nusoap lib to create the web service in php.

```
$ordArr = array("orderid"=>$orderId,"orderdate"=>$orderdate,"ordertype"=>$ordertype);

$userArr = array("userid"=>$userId,"name"=>$name,"address"=>$address);
```

define first complex type for nested array which you want to add into the main array or outer array.

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
 'Order',
 'complexType',
 'struct',
 'all',
 '',
      array(
       'orderid' => array('name' => 'orderid',
           'type' => 'xsd:int'),
       'orderdate' => array('name' => 'orderdate',
           'type' => 'xsd:string'),
       'ordertype' => array('name' => 'ordertype',
           'type' => 'xsd:string'),
      )
);
```

now add this complex type into the main array complex type into the array to define the array type. When you create the complex type as struct/array that type was used to define that object type into the array

now define the user complex type for

```
$userArr = array("userid"=>$userId,"name"=>$name,"address"=>$address,"order"=>$ordArr);

$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
 'User',
 'complexType',
 'struct',
 'all',
 '',
      array(
       'userId' => array('name' => 'userId',
           'type' => 'xsd:int'),
       'name' => array('name' => 'name',
           'type' => 'xsd:string'),
       'address' => array('name' => 'address',
           'type' => 'xsd:string'),
       'order' => array('name' => 'order',
           'type' => 'tns:Order'),
      )
);
```

need more details see this tutorial

[tutorial for nested array](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3arJV7zjQidHQJ%3awww.nonplus.net/geek/000752.php%20create%20complex%20type%20in%20xml%20using%20nusoap%20web%20services%20with%20nested%20array%20in&cd=9&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in&client=firefox-a&source=www.google.co.in)